# Corrupted Excel workbook after POI write from SQL results

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, apache-poi

I run the following class to generate an Excel spreadsheet that will contain the results of my SQL query.  Each time the file is generated, there is an error message when you try to open it up, "Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

I am at the end of my abilities with respect to troubleshooting this as I have used this type of code successfully and have noticed this error arising after the switch to an SSH MySQL connection versus a straight 3306 connection previously.  There are no error messages in the console.

```
package process;

import java.sql.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import java.io.*;


public class WriteMySQLToExcel {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {

         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/wp_dashort", "dashort", "gt9wkk6r1TPnkgrY");
         
         String mark_complete = "SELECT DISTINCT wpgc.user_id, wpgc.timestamp\r\n"
                    + "FROM wp_grassblade_completions as wpgc \r\n" + "  INNER JOIN \r\n"
                    + "  wp_usermeta ON wpgc.user_id = wp_usermeta.user_id\r\n"
                    + "  WHERE wpgc.user_id NOT IN (SELECT atc_reporting.user_id FROM atc_reporting WHERE course = 'SECURITY') AND wpgc.timestamp BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE -INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND content_id IN (1575, 642, 1580) \r\n"
                    + "GROUP BY wpgc.user_id\r\n" + "order BY wpgc.timestamp, wp_usermeta.user_id";
         
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(mark_complete);
         
         XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
         XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Query Results");
         // Create header row
         XSSFRow headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
         for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
           headerRow.createCell(i - 1).setCellValue(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
         }

         int rowNum = 1;
         while (rs.next()) {
           XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
           for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
             row.createCell(i - 1).setCellValue(rs.getString(i));
           }
         }
  
         FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D://testexpdata.xlsx");
         workbook.write(fileOut);
         fileOut.close();
         workbook.close();
         
         rs.close();
         stmt.close();
         conn.close();
      }
   }
```

Code to connect through SSH follows:

```
public class SQLConnection {
private static Connection connection = null;
private static Session session = null;

private static void connectToServer(String dataBaseName) throws SQLException {
    dataBaseName="wp_dashort";
    connectSSH();
    connectToDataBase(dataBaseName);

}

static void connectSSH() throws SQLException {
    String sshHost = "shortguy.ssh.wpengine.net";
    String sshuser = "shortguy";
    String dbuserName = "shortguy";
    String dbpassword = "gt9wgrYpassword";
    String SshKeyFilepath = "c://users//ed25519eclipse";

    int localPort = 3307; // any free port can be used
    String remoteHost = "127.0.0.1";
    int remotePort = 3306;
    String localSSHUrl = "localhost";
    /***************/
    String driverName = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";

    try {
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(sshuser, sshHost, 22);
        jsch.addIdentity(SshKeyFilepath);
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        config.put("ConnectionAttempts", "3");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();

        System.out.println("SSH Connected");

        Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();

        int assinged_port = session.setPortForwardingL(localPort, remoteHost, remotePort);

        System.out.println("localhost:" + assinged_port + " -> " + remoteHost + ":" + remotePort);
        System.out.println("Port Forwarded");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}




POI 5.2.3 
Apache Maven  3.8.7
MySQL Connector  8.0.32
XMLBeans 5.1.1
```

I put the versions at the bottom of the code block above.

Thanks again!

Comment: Are you writing the file to OneDrive or SharePoint? That is, is the mapped drive you are listing as "D" a local drive or one mapped from OneDrive/SharePoint?

Comment: Can you describe a bit more what you mean by "_the switch to an SSH MySQL connection_" here? Your code shown in the question works OK for me - but there is nothing to indicate that this code is using SSH in any way. It looks like a standard TCP/IP connection URL to me (except on port 3307 instead of 3306). How have you set up that SSH tunnel, and how are you using it in your Java code?

Comment: Just as an experiment, I opened my own SSH tunnel to a remote MySQL server (using OpenSSH on Windows as the client). I used your code (different SQL of course) - and my Excel file opened correctly. I am not able to recreate your issue, unfortunately. Maybe as well as showing the SSH details, you can share all the versions you are using (Java, MySQL, the JDBC driver, POI).

Comment: AndrewJames thanks for weighing in.  Can you tell me the versions of your POI jar files, etc.?

Comment: Your Java SSH code works OK for me - it still allows me to generate a valid Excel file. I am using Java 17, POI 5.2.3, MySQL connector 8.0.32 (and MySQL 8), JSch 0.1.55. (You don't need `Class.forName(driverName)` these days - but that is not related to your POI problem). Sorry, I am unable to recreate the problem. Maybe write the SQL result data to a text file - both with the tunnel and without it (if you say adding the tunnel caused the problems to start appearing). That way, you can narrow down things.

Comment: Thanks a ton AndrewJames.  I will follow your guidance and get back on here with the results.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: By the way, I went to the build properties and see that I am using JRE -  JavaSE-1.8
I'm wondering if that would be related...